Show that $S:c_0\to c_0$ given by $S( x_1, x_2,....) = (0,x_1,x_2,..)$ is an isometry for the $l_\infty$ norm
Let $S:c_{0}\to c_{0}$ be given by $S( x_1, x_2,....) = (0,x_1,x_2,..)$. Show that $S$ is an isometry,
where $c_0$ is the subspace of $l_{\infty}$ consisting of sequences which converge to $0$.
My attempt: to prove isometry I need to prove that for any $x,y \in c_0$, $l_{\infty}{(x,y)} = l_{\infty}{(S(x), S(y))}$.
But $l_{\infty}{(x,y)} = \sup\{ | x_{i} - y_{i} | ,\,i \in \mathbb{N} \}$
Thus $l_{\infty}{(x,y)} = l_{\infty}{(S(x), S(y))}$.
But I don't understand where I used that $x$ and $y$ converges to $0$, I think we don't need that.

Did you actually intend to write $l_\infty$ for both the space and the metric?

Sorry but I forget how to write it's metric function so I wrote $l_{\infty}$ as metric function of space, should I change it ?

Your $S$ is indeed the restriction to $c_0$ of an isometry of $\ell^\infty$. It shouldn't worry you.

"I need to prove that for any $x,y \in l_{\infty}$...": you did, but what you  really  needed  was only for any $x,y\in c_0$.

I presume that your definition of the distance should have $i \in \mathbb{N}$, or similar?

Just compute the distances that you have above.

Writing $d_{\infty}{(x,y)} = \sup{ | x_{i} - y_{i} | ,,i \in \mathbb{N} }$ or $| x-y|_{\infty}$ would be standard.

Okay thank you everyone

$S$ is in fact an isometry from $\ell_\infty$ to itself since
$$\sup\{|x_n|:n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\max\big(0,\sup\{|x_{n+1}|: n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\}\big)$$
It only remains to check that $Sx\in \mathcal{c}_0$ if $x\in\mathcal{c}_0$. This is obvious since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n-1}$ for any convergent sequence.
